# regex pattern for quadratic equation

Tags: python, python-re

```
x = 5*x**2+65*x+53    
regex = re.compile(r'\+|-\d*')
```

I tried above to detect + or - then a number pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.split(r'(\+|\-)', x)`. This will return you a list with number elements and `+\-` signs.